# Touchpad is suddenly not working

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, firmware

So today my touchpad suddenly stopped working. I can't move the cursor and can't scroll, however clicking with the dedicated buttons works.

I've updated `linux-firmware`, however the problem didn't occur directly after updating but some hours later and with no reboot in between. I have tried downgrading to `linux-firmware=1.187` and rebooting, but that didn't solve the problem. Installing an even older version might be helpful, since I don't know from what version I upgraded. But I'm unsure how to do this, because I can only find versions 1.187.30 and 1.187.

Here is the output for `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair CORSAIR HS70 Pro Wireless Gaming Headset Consumer Control id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera: FJ Camera                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and for `xinput list-props 13`

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint':
    Device Enabled (184):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (186): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (324): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (325): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (326):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (327):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (328):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (329):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (330):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (331):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (332):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (333):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (334):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (335):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (336):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (337):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (338):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (339):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (340):    1
    libinput Accel Speed (341): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (342): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (343): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (344): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (309): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (310):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (311):    0, 0
    Device Node (312):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (313):    2, 8
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (345):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (346):   1
```

I also tried installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, which lead to almost random scrolling (a lot of scrolling when I touched it and a little when I didn't) and me still not being able to move the cursor.

Hope someone can help, I don't have an external mouse so this is pretty limiting.

Comment: `linux-firmware` is completely unrelated. Try to boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: When booting a previous kernel the touchpad works, thank you! Now do I just wait for a future kernel to solve this?

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.